# install imap in windows

Tags: php, windows, installation, imap

I'm trying to write a script in php that requires imap functions.
I found the functions at [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php).
How do I download and install it in windows ?

Answer (score 17):

> I found the functions at here

No - the link you provided is the documentation for the functions.

I guess you are on a Microsoft Windows platform since you've tagged your question with 'windows' even though its nothing to do with GUIs or data window algorithms (in future it might be a good idea to be a bit more explicit, particularly when talking about installing software).

The imap extension comes as standard with the MSWindows PHP installation. You just need to enable it in your php.ini

Run

```
 <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

To find out what ini file your installation is using. The default php.ini should already contain a line to load the extension but commented out:

```
;extension=php_imap.dll
```

Change this to (or add):

```
extension=php_imap.dll
```

Note that if you are running php within a webserver or as fastcgi, you'll need to restart it for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

just change some line in your php.ini file and problem is solve.

> ;extension=php_imap.dll

to

> extension=php_imap.dll

Answer (score 0):

If someone using **XAMPP package** on the windows machine try to look for **;extension=php_imap** inside the *php.ini* file. And then remove the semicolon when found, I had the same issue while installing the suitecrm.

Comment: This answer is already provided by @AnjaniBarnwal. Please view other answers before posting new ones. And if you wanted to mention `xampp` package, it would be better posted as a comment to the previous answer.

Comment: I was trying to do this in the xampp package, but could not find the exact match, unless I removed .dill extension. But yes from next time I will post these slight changes as a comment.